# need to convert blocks used in iOS to Android Java code

Tags: java, android, iphone, ios

I would like to get started using blocks in my iPhone apps, since they can really be quite handy.

However since all the apps also have to be ported to Android Java, I am not sure if this is a good idea, because I do not have any idea how to easily translate the blocks.

So far porting iOS to Android is straight forward, almost line by line - but how would an iOS block translate to Java ? (of course I am not talking about Java blocks)

Many thanks!

Comment: A quick look at what blocks do in iOS suggests that you could get most of the functionality by using anonymous classes and annotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java allows anonymous (unnamed) classes. What's more, they can extend another class. When used in this fashion, they are similar to blocks in Objective C.

You'll often see an anonymous class defined which implements `Runnable` or similar. This is doing something similar to blocks: providing an anonymous, in-line definition of code that is passed somewhere for later use.

For more info, see the example here: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29#Local_classes_.28Java.29

So in Java you could write something like the following:

```
doMyThing(new Runnable() {
  void run() {
     // your 'block' code here
  }
});
```

The method `doMyThing` could at a later point call the run method (or spawn it as a thread by passing your Runnable into a new Thread object, etc.)

There's further discussion here:

[Limitations of Java Anonymous Classes compared to Objective-C Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192542/limitations-of-java-anonymous-classes-compared-to-objective-c-blocks)

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Objective-C_blocks_vs_Java_Anonymous_Classes_or_Functions_(callbacks)

Comment: so it looks equivalent to bocks - but is there any general difference which I do not see ?

Answer (score 2):

Yea, sadly Java doesn't have closures. For each of the blocks, you'll have to translate this into some sort of callback mechanism. This is the annoying boilerplate required in Java. You gotta constantly do stuff like

```
   button.setOnClickListener(
      new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
           doSomething();)
      }
  });
```

So you have to create an anonymous interface, override the method, and then put your stuff in there, when what you'd really like to be able to do is something like:

```
button.onClick(doSomething(););
```

Comment: but as occulus explains - it seems that the anonymous classes can be used as a substitute of blocks

Comment: uh @user387184, yeah thats why i said "For each of the blocks, you'll have to translate this into some sort of callback mechanism" ... I was just showing how annoying it is that there aren't any blocks in Java...

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
yourObj.passABlock(new actionBlock() {
    public void action() {
        //Whatever
    }
});
```

E.g. Android's [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) class represents a command that can be executed like above (this in a separate thread)

It is essentially implemented using "Command" design pattern.

```
public interface Command {
   void execute();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's easy.

iOS blocks - it's closure. So, Java also have closure. I develop for both platforms - iOS & Android - and i know - this is true.

Please look at wikipedia article http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science) - there are code samples for iOS & Android.

Comment: There is no code sample on that page for Android; the word "android" does not even appear on the page. You will also note that the page has Java listed under "Closure-like constructs", with statements like "Features of some languages simulate some features of closures" and "There have been a number of proposals for adding more fully featured closures to Java".

Comment: Doesn't matter, this is just an example how to convert iOS blocks to Java based project

Comment: please show such example where blocks with parameters and variables of the context are ported to Java - I did not find any on that page